# How to change z-index for primefaces growl component?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, styles, growl

My problem is that, i have a fixed navbar on the top of the page, which has 1030 z-index value. The growl component shows behind the fixed navbar. I tried to override the z-index value for the growl like this (from a custom css file):
`.ui-growl {
    z-index: 9999;
}`
Note: My custom css file is the last one which is loaded:

```
...
 <h:body>
        <f:facet name="last">
            <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="custom.css"/>
        </f:facet>
...
```

When i check the growl component in chrome it has an inline css style with a z-index value:

```
<div id="growl_container" class="ui-growl ui-widget" style="z-index: 1004;">...</div>
```

How should i solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**As .ui-growl has a inline style** . So `z-index:9999` will not override the css. So you have to use **!important** in this case.

> So add !important to your css as below.

```
.ui-growl {
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

**Note :Its not a good practice to use !important** .
I will suggest you to reduce the z-index of navbar ;)

Comment: i read it's not a good practice to use this, so i tried to avoid it. But it works with that, thank you!

Comment: yeah I know that too . So if you have control over navbar reduce its z-index :D But if this answer helped you please accept and upvote.. happy coding ;)

Comment: i tried to upvote but it says i have to wait some minutes to accept an answer after posting the question. you'll get it soon ;)

Comment: as noted by Sahil Dhir, I set my navbar z-index to auto and it worked.